# Loss of tuid in TMX files after editing them in SDL Trados Studio

Tags: zend-framework

I've got TMX files that have a tuid that is used by the Zend Framework to translate my application's texts. However, after importing the TMX files in SDL Trados Studio, and re-exporting them, the tuid is missing. Other editors, like Heartsome TMX editor, do preserve the TUID. However, my translation agency is using SDL Trados, so I would like to know if there's a way to preserver this tuid.

Comment: Hello, I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head.  But if you can share the TMX I'd be happy to take a look and maybe find the problem?

Comment: An example is at http://pastebin.com/seUdpKsf

The tuid is used in the code, and that's lost after the import/export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio doesn’t need the TUIDs and therefore drops them during import. One way would be to run a script on the TMX to convert the TUIDs to custom field values, but then these are also ignored by the Studio import unless the TMX flavor is one of the known ones (SDLX, Studio, Workbench).

Unfortunately this is typical of data loss when processing third-party TMX in Studio. We only preserve all the data in the TMX if it’s one of our flavors as otherwise we don’t know how to interpret that data. It boils down to TMX’ complete lack of semantic specification.

Interesting that Heartsome preserves it though.

Comment: I've done something similar by moving the tuids to a separate language. Since the tuid is usually the 'original' translation (though not always perfect English), it can be used as the source translation.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that can handle those TMX properties is Wordbee Translator, it keeps the properties so that when you export the file, they are still there.

Some properties and metadata as:
changedate
creationDate
srclang
notes
tuid